# Family of sequences in a Hilbert space with certain property

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of sequences on the unit sphere of $l_2$ with the following property: For any sequence $\varepsilon_n\downarrow 0$ but which is not eventually identically $0$, there exists $(x_n)\in\mathcal{F}$ and $z\in S_{l_2}$ such that, for any $n$, $\langle z, x_n\rangle\leq \varepsilon_n$. Can we find a sequence $(y_n)\in\mathcal{F}$ and $z\in S_{l_2}$ such that for any $n$ $\langle z, y_n\rangle=0$?

Comment: What do you mean by $S_{l_2}$?

Comment: If $\mathcal F$ is a vector space, thus $0\in \mathcal F$, and the claim follows trivially.

Comment: Unit sphere of $l_2$.

Comment: @daw You are right. Fixed, I require the sequence to be non-zero.

Comment: I edited the original question, it had a fairly easy counterexample. Now, the question seems less trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it does not work.

Construct $\mathcal F=\{z_n, \ n\in\mathbb N\}$ as the set of sequences defined in the following way:
$z_n=(z_{n,k})$ will be the sequence of elements in $l^2$ with 
$$
z_{n,k} = \begin{cases}\frac1n e_{1} + \frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}ne_{2} & \text{ if } k=1\\
\frac1n e_{2} + \frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}ne_{k+1} & \text{ if } k>1.\\
\end{cases}
$$

If $\epsilon_m\to0$ is given, take $n>\epsilon_1^{-1}$, $x=z_n$, $z=e_1$. Then 
$$
\langle x_k,z\rangle = \langle z_{n,k},e_1\rangle = 
\begin{cases}\frac1n \le \epsilon_1& \text{ if } k=1\\ 0\le \epsilon_k& \text{ otherwise. } \end{cases}
$$

Now let $z\in l^2$ with $\|z\|=1$. Assume $\langle z_{n,k},z\rangle=0$ for all $k$. 
Let $k\ge 2$. Then
$$
0 = \langle z_{n,k} - z_{n,k+1} ,z\rangle  = \frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}n (z_{k+1}-z_{k+2}).
$$
Hence $z_{k+1}=z_{k+2}$ for $k\ge 2$. Since $z\in l^2$ this implies $z_k=0$ for all $k\ge 3$. From $\langle z_{n,2},z\rangle=0$ it follows $z_2=0$, and
$\langle z_{n,1},z\rangle=0$ implies $z_1=0$. Hence $z=0$ a contradiction.

Comment: I don't think this is a counterexample. I don't ask that $z$ "cancels" all elements of $\mathcal{F}$, but only one. If you take $z=\sqrt{2}\sum_i\frac{1}{(\sqrt{3})^{i}}e_i$, then $\langle z, z_{2,k} \rangle=0$ for any $k$.

Comment: I mean $$z=\sqrt{2}\sum_i(-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{3})^i}e_i$$

Comment: I tried to adjust the counterexample. Please check again.

Comment: Yes, I think it's all good now. Thanks!